# Converting an unknown data structure to a known data structure in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I recently used an API to pull in some data from a platform I use.

But the problem is, the data that I pulled, is not a recognized data structure.

It's almost a list of dictionaries, with some extra stuff.

I need to know how can I convert it to a recognized data structure. I don't necessarily need the code to do so, just a north on what I need to study would be helpful already. I'm new to Python and I don't have a lot of coding experience.

I have a file with this data in each line, this is a sample line from the file:

```
[<OrderProducts at 0x24333f0, {'price_ex_tax': '99.0000', 'event_date': '', 'wrapping_name': '', 'price_tax': '0.0000', 'id': 3, 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000', 'bin_picking_number': '', 'ebay_transaction_id': '', 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_total': '99.0000', 'quantity': 1, 'ebay_item_id': '', 'type': 'physical', 'product_id': 83, 'price_inc_tax': '99.0000', 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'parent_order_product_id': None, 'option_set_id': 15, 'wrapping_message': '', 'weight': '3.0000', 'refund_amount': '0.0000', 'applied_discounts': [{'amount': 99, 'id': 'total-coupon'}], 'event_name': None, 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_price': '99.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'total_inc_tax': '99.0000', 'total_ex_tax': '99.0000', 'quantity_shipped': 0, 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000', 'total_tax': '0.0000', 'sku': 'S-TIM-BAC-STD', 'return_id': 0, 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'name': 'University of Timbuktu Bachelor Set', 'is_bundled_product ': False, 'order_id': 614534, 'configurable_fields': [], 'order_address_id': 2, 'is_refunded': False, 'product_options': [{'display_style': 'Pick list', 'type': 'Product list', 'product_option_id': 95, 'display_value': 'Cambridge-Style Bachelor Gown, Size L', 'id': 2, 'option_id': 19, 'value': '77', 'display_name': 'Gown size', 'name': 'Bachelor gown size', 'order_product_id': 3}, {'display_style': 'Pick list', 'type': 'Product list', 'product_option_id': 97, 'display_value': 'Bachelor and Masters Trencher, Size L', 'id': 3, 'option_id': 20, 'value': '80', 'display_name': 'Trencher size', 'name': 'Trencher size', 'order_product_id': 3}], 'base_cost_price': '0.0000'}>, <OrderProducts at 0x2433420, {'price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'event_date': '', 'wrapping_name': '', 'price_tax': '0.0000', 'id': 4, 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000', 'bin_picking_number': '', 'ebay_transaction_id': '', 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_total': '0.0000', 'quantity': 1, 'ebay_item_id': '', 'type': 'physical', 'product_id': 80, 'price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'parent_order_product_id': 3, 'option_set_id': None, 'wrapping_message': '', 'weight': '0.0000', 'refund_amount': '0.0000', 'applied_discounts': [], 'event_name': None, 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_price': '0.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'total_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'total_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'quantity_shipped': 0, 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000', 'total_tax': '0.0000', 'sku': 'G-CAM-BAC-L', 'return_id': 0, 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'name': 'Cambridge-Style Bachelor Gown, Size L', 'is_bundled_product ': True, 'order_id': 614534, 'configurable_fields': [], 'order_address_id': 2, 'is_refunded': False, 'product_options': [], 'base_cost_price': '0.0000'}>, <OrderProducts at 0x2433450, {'price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'event_date': '', 'wrapping_name': '', 'price_tax': '0.0000', 'id': 5, 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000', 'bin_picking_number': '', 'ebay_transaction_id': '', 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_total': '0.0000', 'quantity': 1, 'ebay_item_id': '', 'type': 'physical', 'product_id': 87, 'price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'parent_order_product_id': 3, 'option_set_id': None, 'wrapping_message': '', 'weight': '0.0000', 'refund_amount': '0.0000', 'applied_discounts': [], 'event_name': None, 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_price': '0.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'total_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'total_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'quantity_shipped': 0, 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000', 'total_tax': '0.0000', 'sku': 'C-STD-B&M-L', 'return_id': 0, 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'name': 'Bachelor and Masters Trencher, Size L', 'is_bundled_product ': True, 'order_id': 614534, 'configurable_fields': [], 'order_address_id': 2, 'is_refunded': False, 'product_options': [], 'base_cost_price': '0.0000'}>]
```

EDIT: This is the code I got:

```
import ast
import re

order_item = re.compile("<OrderProducts at 0x[\da-f]+, ({.*?})>", re.I)

 with open('allOrderProducts2') as inf:
     for line in inf:
        order = [ast.literal_eval(op) for op in re.findall(order_item, line)]
        # ta-da! Now do something with the order
        f = open("test", "w", encoding='utf-8')
        f.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), order)))
        f.close()
```

Comment: Looks like JSON data - check out the `json` module.

Comment: [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can be useful for this case.

Comment: @Marcin Tried it, still getting syntax error. Checking `json` module.

Comment: `map` is generally disrecommended; instead do `f.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in order))`

Comment: Changed and still no go. Only the last line out of all is saved.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I was opening and closing the file inside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list (`[ ... ]`) containing three `OrderProducts` objects which, when printed, represent themselves as dictionaries (`{ key1: value1, key2: value2 }`).

---

**Edit:** ok, you have the **string representation** of three OrderProducts etc.

So the first order of business is to convert to actual Python data structures, like so:

```
import ast
import re

order_items = re.compile("<OrderProducts at 0x[\da-f]+, ({.*?})>", re.I).findall

with open(FILENAME) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        order = [ast.literal_eval(op) for op in order_items(line)]
        # ta-da! Now do something with the order
```

then continue as before:

---

**Edit2:**

Cleaned up a bit:

```
import re

DATA = "allOrderProducts2"
RESULT = "test"

order_items = re.compile("<OrderProducts at 0x[\da-f]+, ({.*?})>", re.I).findall

with open(DATA) as inf, open(RESULT, "w", "utf-8") as outf:
    # Instead of reading each line separately,
    # we can just parse the whole file in one gulp
    for item_str in order_items(inf.read()):
        # Also no need to convert the data
        # just to cast it back to a string again
        outf.write(item_str + "\n")
```

Then, when reading the RESULT file back in, you can pass each line to `ast.literal_eval` to turn it back into a dict.

---

Looking at the `id` and `parent_order_product_id` fields, it looks like what you have is a "University of Timbuktu Bachelor Set" consisting of a "Cambridge-Style Bachelor Gown, Size L" and "Bachelor and Masters Trencher, Size L" with a package price of 99.0 (units unknown) and no tax.

I wrote a quick script to figure out what a default OrderProduct looks like:

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint as pp

data = [
    {'price_ex_tax': '99.0000', 'event_date': '', 'wrapping_name': '', 'price_tax': '0.0000', 'id': 3, 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000', 'bin_picking_number': '', 'ebay_transaction_id': '', 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_total': '99.0000', 'quantity': 1, 'ebay_item_id': '', 'type': 'physical', 'product_id': 83, 'price_inc_tax': '99.0000', 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'parent_order_product_id': None, 'option_set_id': 15, 'wrapping_message': '', 'weight': '3.0000', 'refund_amount': '0.0000', 'applied_discounts': [{'amount': 99, 'id': 'total-coupon'}], 'event_name': None, 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_price': '99.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'total_inc_tax': '99.0000', 'total_ex_tax': '99.0000', 'quantity_shipped': 0, 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000', 'total_tax': '0.0000', 'sku': 'S-TIM-BAC-STD', 'return_id': 0, 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'name': 'University of Timbuktu Bachelor Set', 'is_bundled_product ': False, 'order_id': 614534, 'configurable_fields': [], 'order_address_id': 2, 'is_refunded': False, 'product_options': [{'display_style': 'Pick list', 'type': 'Product list', 'product_option_id': 95, 'display_value': 'Cambridge-Style Bachelor Gown, Size L', 'id': 2, 'option_id': 19, 'value': '77', 'display_name': 'Gown size', 'name': 'Bachelor gown size', 'order_product_id': 3}, {'display_style': 'Pick list', 'type': 'Product list', 'product_option_id': 97, 'display_value': 'Bachelor and Masters Trencher, Size L', 'id': 3, 'option_id': 20, 'value': '80', 'display_name': 'Trencher size', 'name': 'Trencher size', 'order_product_id': 3}], 'base_cost_price': '0.0000'},
    {'price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'event_date': '', 'wrapping_name': '', 'price_tax': '0.0000', 'id': 4, 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000', 'bin_picking_number': '', 'ebay_transaction_id': '', 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_total': '0.0000', 'quantity': 1, 'ebay_item_id': '', 'type': 'physical', 'product_id': 80, 'price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'parent_order_product_id': 3, 'option_set_id': None, 'wrapping_message': '', 'weight': '0.0000', 'refund_amount': '0.0000', 'applied_discounts': [], 'event_name': None, 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_price': '0.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'total_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'total_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'quantity_shipped': 0, 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000', 'total_tax': '0.0000', 'sku': 'G-CAM-BAC-L', 'return_id': 0, 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'name': 'Cambridge-Style Bachelor Gown, Size L', 'is_bundled_product ': True, 'order_id': 614534, 'configurable_fields': [], 'order_address_id': 2, 'is_refunded': False, 'product_options': [], 'base_cost_price': '0.0000'}, 
    {'price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'event_date': '', 'wrapping_name': '', 'price_tax': '0.0000', 'id': 5, 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000', 'bin_picking_number': '', 'ebay_transaction_id': '', 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_total': '0.0000', 'quantity': 1, 'ebay_item_id': '', 'type': 'physical', 'product_id': 87, 'price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000', 'parent_order_product_id': 3, 'option_set_id': None, 'wrapping_message': '', 'weight': '0.0000', 'refund_amount': '0.0000', 'applied_discounts': [], 'event_name': None, 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'base_price': '0.0000', 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000', 'total_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'total_ex_tax': '0.0000', 'quantity_shipped': 0, 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000', 'total_tax': '0.0000', 'sku': 'C-STD-B&M-L', 'return_id': 0, 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000', 'name': 'Bachelor and Masters Trencher, Size L', 'is_bundled_product ': True, 'order_id': 614534, 'configurable_fields': [], 'order_address_id': 2, 'is_refunded': False, 'product_options': [], 'base_cost_price': '0.0000'}
]

def get_defaults(lst_of_dct):
    defaults = {}
    majority = (len(data) + 1) // 2
    for key in lst_of_dct[0]:
        try:
            ctr = Counter(d[key] for d in lst_of_dct)
            value,count = ctr.most_common(1)[0]
            defaults[key] = value if count >= majority else ""
        except TypeError:
            # Counter doesn't like unhashable type ie lists
            defaults[key] = []
    return defaults

defaults = get_defaults(data)
pp(defaults)
```

which gives

```
{'applied_discounts': [],
 'base_cost_price': '0.0000',
 'base_price': '0.0000',
 'base_total': '0.0000',
 'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000',
 'bin_picking_number': '',
 'configurable_fields': [],
 'cost_price_ex_tax': '0.0000',
 'cost_price_inc_tax': '0.0000',
 'cost_price_tax': '0.0000',
 'ebay_item_id': '',
 'ebay_transaction_id': '',
 'event_date': '',
 'event_name': None,
 'fixed_shipping_cost': '0.0000',
 'id': '',
 'is_bundled_product ': True,
 'is_refunded': False,
 'name': '',
 'option_set_id': None,
 'order_address_id': 2,           # should be 0
 'order_id': 614534,              # should be 0
 'parent_order_product_id': 3,    # should be 0
 'price_ex_tax': '0.0000',
 'price_inc_tax': '0.0000',
 'price_tax': '0.0000',
 'product_id': '',
 'product_options': [],
 'quantity': 1,                   # should be 0
 'quantity_shipped': 0,
 'refund_amount': '0.0000',
 'return_id': 0,
 'sku': '',
 'total_ex_tax': '0.0000',
 'total_inc_tax': '0.0000',
 'total_tax': '0.0000',
 'type': 'physical',
 'weight': '0.0000',
 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax': '0.0000',
 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax': '0.0000',
 'wrapping_cost_tax': '0.0000',
 'wrapping_message': '',
 'wrapping_name': ''}
```

After manually checking and fixing some bad default values,

```
def strip_defaults(dct, defaults):
    return {key:value for key,value in dct.items() if value != defaults[key]}

res = [strip_defaults(d, defaults) for d in data]
pp(res)
```

which removes all default-valued fields and gives us a slightly more readable version:

```
[{'applied_discounts': [{'amount': 99, 'id': 'total-coupon'}],
  'base_price': '99.0000',
  'base_total': '99.0000',
  'id': 3,
  'is_bundled_product ': False,
  'name': 'University of Timbuktu Bachelor Set',
  'option_set_id': 15,
  'order_address_id': 2,
  'order_id': 614534,
  'price_ex_tax': '99.0000',
  'price_inc_tax': '99.0000',
  'product_id': 83,
  'product_options': [{'display_name': 'Gown size',
                       'display_style': 'Pick list',
                       'display_value': 'Cambridge-Style Bachelor Gown, '
                                        'Size L',
                       'id': 2,
                       'name': 'Bachelor gown size',
                       'option_id': 19,
                       'order_product_id': 3,
                       'product_option_id': 95,
                       'type': 'Product list',
                       'value': '77'},
                      {'display_name': 'Trencher size',
                       'display_style': 'Pick list',
                       'display_value': 'Bachelor and Masters Trencher, '
                                        'Size L',
                       'id': 3,
                       'name': 'Trencher size',
                       'option_id': 20,
                       'order_product_id': 3,
                       'product_option_id': 97,
                       'type': 'Product list',
                       'value': '80'}],
  'quantity': 1,
  'sku': 'S-TIM-BAC-STD',
  'total_ex_tax': '99.0000',
  'total_inc_tax': '99.0000',
  'weight': '3.0000'},
 {'id': 4,
  'name': 'Cambridge-Style Bachelor Gown, Size L',
  'order_address_id': 2,
  'order_id': 614534,
  'parent_order_product_id': 3,
  'product_id': 80,
  'quantity': 1,
  'sku': 'G-CAM-BAC-L'},
 {'id': 5,
  'name': 'Bachelor and Masters Trencher, Size L',
  'order_address_id': 2,
  'order_id': 614534,
  'parent_order_product_id': 3,
  'product_id': 87,
  'quantity': 1,
  'sku': 'C-STD-B&M-L'}]
```

Comment: That seems right, but I can't rely on manually removing the unnecessary parts. I currently have a file with more than a thousand lines, each with a line like the one that I posted, and I'll keep pulling more data, so I need a way to remove them automatically.

Comment: @iamfbpt: you should be able to read each line, use re.findall to pull out each dict string, then ast.literal_eval to convert it to a Python data structure; sample code to follow shortly.

Comment: Thanks, it's making more sense now :)

Comment: Editing my post with code I got. For some reason, the last line is overriding hte other, so I end up having just one line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a python string representation of a list of objects. The form seems to be:

```
[<_Classname_ at _memory_address_, _dict_>, ...]
```

The following will extract the dictionary values.

```
import ast

def extract_dicts(data_string):
    s = data_string.strip()
    items = []
    while True:
         start = s.index("{")
         s = s[start:]
         try:
             ast.literal_eval(s)
             raise ValueError("malformed list")
         except SyntaxError as e:
             end = e.offset

         items.append(ast.literal_eval(s[:end-2]))
         s = s[end-2:]
         if s == ">]":
             break
    return items
```

Comment: I need the whole dictionaries, not just the values!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a list of `OrderProducts` class instances list, the `0x24333f0` is the address of then instance in memory. It's almost useless as it's not data structure for transform data, but a readable print of exist instance in current running program.
maybe your platform just use a `print([OrderProducts_instance])` to print out this, which is not intent for transform data but for read. You should never use this for transform data as it only for **read** not for **transform**
However if you still want to parser current data, following step maybe a solution:

- transform to json format

  - you may remove then `[<OrderProducts at 0x24333f0,`, only keep content start from `{` and end with `}` which could be a dict in json.
  - replace all `'` to `"` as json format only allow `"` to quote data
- Use python `json` module to load data

Though the best solution for this is connect to your platform for a new api for pull data

Comment: That's the only data I can pull in, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the slightly wonky output from a list of classes that didn't define a `str` or `repr` method properly. You seem to have three objects with content that looks like a dictionary (of dictionaries and lists) like this:

```
[<OrderProducts at 0x24333f0, {...},
 <OrderProducts at 0x2433420, {...},
 <OrderProducts at 0x2433450, {...}>
]
```

I guess `0x...` is where they were in memory when the output was produced. So to get you started (quick and dirty, no money-back guarantees)

```
import ast
import re
patt = patt = '<OrderProducts\sat\s0x.......,\s({.*})'
matches = re.findall(patt, data)
[ast.literal_eval(match)  for match in matches]
```

returns a list of dictionaries with your data in:

```
[{'applied_discounts': [{'amount': 99, 'id': 'total-coupon'}],
  'base_cost_price': '0.0000',
  'base_price': '99.0000',
  'base_total': '99.0000',
  'base_wrapping_cost': '0.0000',
  'bin_picking_number': '',
  'configurable_fields': [],
```

Note that you're not done: a lot of these fields look like they really want to be `float`s or `int`s but they're still strings.